# Why does my collection not emit?

Tags: rendering, particles, hair

I try to render some gras objects as hair particle.
Under Render I selected **"Render As: Collection"**. And its all fine.
But as soon as I check **"Whole collection"** all particles disapear.
Does someone know why that is or how to fix that?
[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It could be a question of orientation of the elements in the collection. Have you looked below the ground? I'm pretty sure they're there, upside down. With all collection's elements selected, rotate them around x,y,z axes and see what happens. Note: your grass strands should be aligned along the +x axis, with their origin located on the roots.

Comment: Well they are and they are not under the ground. I found them. For some reason they are scattered many units below the ground. Not even like they are placed at the same heights of the plane but completely random.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your elements: make sure 1) alignment is along +x axis (as said above) 2) make sure the origin for each mesh is where it should be (i.e. at the base of the grass strands). In solid view, the origin of the mesh (when selected) is indicated by a yellow dot and this yellow dot should be on the basis of the mesh. If it doesn't work, you might consider sharing your file so that we can have a look. (Note: if you have proprietary assets, then replace them with a Suzanne, for example, :-) but make sure orientiation, scale  and location are the same.)

[image]